# How to add solr core in windows?

Tags: solr, pysolr, solr-schema, solrconfig

Downloaded (Apache solr 8.8.1) [https://archive.apache.org/dist/lucene/solr/8.1.1/]

In path \solr-8.8.1\bin

Opened command prompt, and executed following command

`solr start`

[command prompt screen after starting solr core](https://i.stack.imgur.com/GHxXM.png)

Accessed http://localhost:8983/solr/#/ in the browser

clicked on -> Core Admin -> new core

*filled core name, instanceDir, dataDir- data, config- (by default) solrconfig.xml , schema- (by default) schema.xml *

When i click on Add core,

I get following error:

`Error CREATEing SolrCore 'new_core': Unable to create core [new_core] Caused by: Can't find resource 'solrconfig.xml' in classpath or 'C:\Users\AnanyaStitipragyan\Desktop\CollabAI\solr-8.8.1\server\solr\new_core'`

Answer (score 0):

you can add core using following command

solr-8.8.1\bin>

`solr create -c <core_name>`

Check out this link https://www.tutorialspoint.com/apache_solr/apache_solr_core.htm